# Getting a selected property from a getter

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuex

I have an array of containers in my state and I'm trying to setup a getter that splits it into active and inactive containers.

```
containers: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'test container',
    image: 'some image',
    state: 'running',
    status: 'Running'
}, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'another test container',
    image: 'some image',
    state: 'stopped',
    status: 'Running'
}]
```

I'm using this to get the array below.

```
export const x = state => _.partition(state.containers, c => c.state === 'running');
```

The problem with this is I want it split and assigned to activeContainers and stoppedContainers and then exported.

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "test container",
      "image": "some image",
      "state": "running",
      "status": "Running"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "another test container",
      "image": "some image",
      "state": "stopped",
      "status": "Running"
    }
  ]
]
```

I've tried using ES6's deconstruction but I think I'm missing something or putting the deconstruction in the wrong place for it to work with Vuex.

```
export const [activeContainers = [], stoppedContainers = []] = state => _.partition(state.containers, c => c.state === 'running');
```

Comment: You're trying to assign a function to an array. That can't go well.

Comment: I just want to export the results of the _.partition but instead of getting back 2 arrays I want one. I know there's easier ways I just wanted to see if it was possible to do it like this.

Comment: You are currently exporting a *function* `x`, not a `state` object or `containers` array. So how would you get from there to exporting two arrays?!

Comment: So I'd be better off just returning a single array in the partition section and then duplicating it but return the other array in the other getter?

Comment: You want to do the destructuring at the place where `x` is called

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that as vuex is built around doing stuff like that in a central location which would be inside of the getter itself.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write a getter that creates two properties at once

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145
After reading this I'm thinking there may be away around this using some of the stuff they've mentioned. I'm going to leave this open and see if anyone else has any ideas as it'd be nice if this was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Returning `functions` from a `getter`

As per the comments go by in the question, it is indeed true that you can't have two properties mapped by a `getter`. Reading more that you didn't want another getter for the `activeContainers` and `stoppedContainers`

After going through the [link](http://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145%20A) you shared, I found a way you could still have something very close to a parameterized `getter`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pdp6zjom/) you can see it in full effect.

```
getters = {
  getContainer: (state) => {
    const [activeContainer = [], inactiveContainer = []] = _.partition(state.containers, c => c.state === 'running')
    return (container) => {
      return (container === 'activeContainer') // returned function
       ? activeContainer
       : inactiveContainer    
    }
  }
}
```

Here in this getter, I am returning a function, which can accept parameters and get something very close to what you desire.

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I wanted as I not know I have to export a function and not just an array so it'll accept it.

Comment: @AlexisTyler This is what the github issue contained. In the thread you shared, I read that this is an advisable pattern. Also could you edit the question header, as it is not as much about destructuring in vuex but getting a selected property from a getter. Although I too would like to see if there could be an even more flexible way to do so. :)